# Why do I have to create a Map in AutoMapper

Tags: c#, automapper

Why do I have to call the .CreateMap method?

Actually its totally obviously that calling the .Map method has the same source/destination parameter.

Is this a typical case "if you dont like the software do not use it"

or is there an easier less cumbersome way to make a mapping in one line I do not know of?

```
Mapper.CreateMap<ReleaseViewModel, Release>();
Release release = (Release)Mapper.Map(releaseViewModel, typeof(ReleaseViewModel), typeof(Release));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can see the "CreateMap<>" as method to register your mapping with automapper.
The "Map()" is actualy executing the mapping registered.

The "CreateMap<>" has extra methods to fine grain your mapping, which is by itself a reason to seperate those two methods. Think of it as "Seperation of Concern"-principle.

**One liner wrapper**

```
public abstract class Mapper<TFrom, TTo>
{
    private void Configure()
    {
        Mapper.CreateMap<TFrom, TTo>();
    }

    public TTo Map(TFrom @from)
    {
        Configure();
        return Mapper.Map<TFrom, TTo>(@from);
    }

    public IEnumerable<TTo> Map(IEnumerable<TFrom> fromList)
    {
        return fromList == null
            ? null 
            : fromList.Select(Map).ToList();
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes its true that CreateMap can do complex stuff. But when I want a 1:1 Mapping the author should still offer a one liner. I dont want to build an architecture around some property copy stuff ;-)

Comment: I think you can easily work you way around that with a simple wrapper on the Automapper.Mapper object. Check my edit.

Answer (score 4):

I was baffled by the same thing for a while, what if I wanted to just map object a-b with zero configuration? Well it turns out there is a way:

```
Mapper.DynamicMap<MyType>(mySourceObject);
```

Map is intended to be used in the situation where the contract between source and target is always explicitly defined. An omission of this contract is thus breaking this usage principle.

Answer (score 0):

It's a way to register mappings into AutoMapper. One advantage to this method is that you can call

```
Mapper.AssertConfigurationIsValid();
```

to check if the mappings are valid.

To make it easier, you can create a single place where you place all the mappings (e.g. for ASP.NET MVC you can place it in the ApplicationStart in the Global.asax)

btw, for your Map-method, you can also use the following:

```
Release release = Mapper.Map<ReleaseViewModel,Release>(releaseViewModel);
```

Comment: yes i saw the another method but know I understand its meaning lol ;-) I tried valueinjecter and its perfect except it does not return a business object (Release) it must always instantiated manually :/ I am looking for a one-liner tool...

Answer (score 0):

gotcha... EmitMapper: a one liner but ugly to read as hell ;-)

```
Release release = ObjectMapperManager.DefaultInstance.GetMapper<ReleaseViewModel,Release>().Map(releaseViewModel);
```

http://emitmapper.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 0):

This is why I prefer Value Injector for simple 1<->1 mappings.  Read about it here: http://valueinjecter.codeplex.com/

It is as simple as:

```
myObject.InjectFrom(anyOtherObject);
```

And will implicitly map properties with same names and types.

Comment: Read my comment to user "Pbirkoff" then you know why valueinjecter is not a one liner :)